# How to set columnOption looping throw all column?

Tags: devexpress, angular7

How to set the `columnOptions` looping through all in angular devexpress module?

at present I do one by one like :

```
onInitialized(e) {

        e.component.columnOption("Id", {
            allowHeaderFiltering : false -> 1
        })

        e.component.columnOption("Name", {
            allowHeaderFiltering : false -> 2
        })

        e.component.columnOption("SaleAmount", {
            editorOptions: {
                format: "currency",
                showClearButton: true
            }
        });
    }
```

How to look all column and set the `columnOptionon` each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to initialize a column with default settings (I believe you need to do this since you provided the `onInitialized` event handler code), use the [customizeColumns](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/#customizeColumns) callback function. Its parameter is an array of all columns in the grid. Thus, you can traverse through all columns as you do in a regular array.

Since `customizeColumns` is a callback function, use square brackets to assign a function to it in Angular as described in the [Callback Functions](https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-angular#callback-functions) section:

***.component.html**

```
<dx-data-grid [customizeColumns]="customizeColumns">
</dx-data-grid>
```

***.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
    customizeColumns (columns) {
        columns.forEach(c => c.width = 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show me a demo? I am using angular7.0 with devxreme 18.2  the method not calling for me at all

Comment: The link I provided (https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/#customizeColumns) contains an example for Angular: https://monosnap.com/file/PAHNARbZrUwPKPfNQn1aiYB4KpyJ49

Comment: I also updated my answer to show how to use this callback function